# Recurrence relation with ternary strings (at least two consecutive same numbers)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let c_n be the number of strings in {0,1,2} of
length n that contain at least two consecutive
symbols that are the same, i.e., 00, 11, or 22.
Find a recurrence relation for c_n when n >= 2.
What are c_0 and c_1?

My work:
c_0 and c_1 are obviously 0. I found that c_2 = 3 and c_3=15 by inspection, however I can not derive a recurrence relation. Intuitively, I thought that c_n might be 4*c_n-1 + 3 but I can not prove it. I thought about adding new numbers to left and right sides of the existing strings but there will be duplicates. How should I approach to this question?

Comment: It may be easier to count the complement on this one; but that doesn't give a recurrence relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Say that a ternary string is *good* if it contains two consecutive identical symbols and *bad* otherwise. Suppose that $t_1\ldots t_nt_{n+1}$ is good. Then exactly one of two things must be true: either $t_1\ldots t_n$ is good, or $t_1\ldots t_n$ is bad **and** $t_n=t_{n+1}$.

- Show that there are $3c_n$ good strings $t_1\ldots t_nt_{n+1}$ of length $n+1$ such that $t_1\ldots t_n$ is good.
- Show that there are $3^n-c_n$ bad strings of length $n$ and explain why there are therefore $3^n-c_n$ good strings $t_1\ldots t_nt_{n+1}$ such that $t_1\ldots t_n$ is bad.
- Combine these results to get a recurrence expressing $c_{n+1}$ in terms of $c_n$ and $n$.